# Issue with query planner in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have this query which has suddenly turned really really slow

```
select * 
from satelliteproduct 
where supplier_id = 226 
and supplierproduct_id IN ('123', '234');
```

If I query an explain analyze I can see that it is actually doing a seq scan instead of using the indexes.

```
Index Scan using unq_satelliteproduct_0 on satelliteproduct (cost=0.69..2.71 rows=1 width=2593)    
  Index Cond: (supplier_id = 226)
  Filter: ((supplierproduct_id)::text = ANY ('{123,234}'::text[]))
```

The weird thing though is if change the value of supplier_id and it suddenly becomes really fast and I can see that it does use the indexes properly, ie

```
Index Scan using unq_satelliteproduct_0 on satelliteproduct (cost=0.69..4.41 rows=1 width=2593) (actual time=0.088..0.089 rows=0 loops=1)    
  Index Cond: ((supplier_id = 4207) AND ((supplierproduct_id)::text = ANY ('{123,234}'::text[])))
```

Any idea? It started happening after an "abrupt" shutdown when data was being inserted. The db recovered well and I performed a vacuum analyze.

EDIT

Information on the indexes, from \d+ satelliteproduct

```
                                          Table 

"public.satelliteproduct"
       Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 productid          | character varying(100)      |           | not null |         | extended |              |
 center             | geometry                    |           |          |         | main     |              |
 cloud              | double precision            |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 gsd                | double precision            |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 hashvalue          | character varying(100)      |           |          |         | extended |              |
 ona                | double precision            |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 orbit              | integer                     |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 orbitdirection     | character varying(255)      |           |          |         | extended |              |
 originalql         | character varying(1000)     |           |          |         | extended |              |
 oza                | double precision            |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 polarisation       | character varying(255)      |           |          |         | extended |              |
 quicklookurl       | character varying(1000)     |           |          |         | extended |              |
 sensormode_id      | bigint                      |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 startacq           | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 stopacq            | timestamp without time zone |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 stripid            | character varying(100)      |           |          |         | extended |              |
 supplierproduct_id | character varying(100)      |           |          |         | extended |              |
 sza                | double precision            |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 thumbnailurl       | character varying(1000)     |           |          |         | extended |              |
 sensorbeam_id      | bigint                      |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 supplier_id        | bigint                      |           |          |         | plain    |              |
 footgeom           | geometry                    |           |          |         | main     |              |
 footgeog           | geography                   |           |          |         | main     |              |
 vendorparameters   | json                        |           |          |         | extended |              |
 stereo             | character varying(1000)     |           |          |         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "satelliteproduct_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (productid)
    "unq_satelliteproduct_0" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (supplier_id, supplierproduct_id)
    "footgeogidx" gist (footgeog)
    "sensormodeidx" btree (sensormode_id)
    "starttimeidx" btree (startacq)
    "supplierproductidx" btree (supplierproduct_id)
    "timerangeidx" btree (startacq, stopacq)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_satelliteproduct_sensorbeam_id" FOREIGN KEY (sensorbeam_id) REFERENCES sensorbeam(id)
    "fk_satelliteproduct_supplier_id" FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) REFERENCES supplier(id)
```

Postgres version from select version();

> PostgreSQL 11.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian
> 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Regarding cardinality, there are around 40M+ rows.

The database runs on a k8s pod, with 8GB RAM, in a primary / read configuration. This is the primary db and is only used for building the database content.

I can also add that if I run the following query

```
select * 
from satelliteproduct 
where supplier_id = 226 
and supplierproduct_id '123';
```

Then the result is immediate. BUT if I run

```
select * 
from satelliteproduct 
where supplier_id = 226 
and supplierproduct_id IN ('123', '234');
```

(notice the difference is with the IN) then it takes 10mns!

I haven't yet dropped and rebuilt all indexes, just a vacuum analyze. I will do if you think it's worth it given the new information I provided.

Edit 2

I did some more tests.

Dead tuples

```
 schemaname |      relname      | n_live_tup | n_dead_tup | last_autovacuum
------------+-------------------+------------+------------+-----------------
 public     | satelliteproduct  |     376841 |     665594 |
 pg_catalog | pg_depend         |          0 |         77 |
 pg_toast   | pg_toast_18014    |         18 |         30 |
 public     | importtask        |       2383 |        242 |
 pg_toast   | pg_toast_17987    |       3839 |        313 |
 public     | importplannedtask |          4 |         17 |
 pg_catalog | pg_statistic      |          0 |         16 |
 pg_toast   | pg_toast_2619     |          1 |         13 |
 public     | ingestor          |          0 |         12 |
 pg_catalog | pg_class          |          0 |          5 |
(10 rows)
```

I retried the vacuum first, this time with Verbose, looks like the vacuum hadn't worked properly before

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE) satelliteproduct;
INFO:  vacuuming "public.satelliteproduct"
INFO:  scanned index "satelliteproduct_pkey" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 34.66 s, system: 0.61 s, elapsed: 90.05 s
INFO:  scanned index "supplierproductidx" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 14.25 s, system: 2.91 s, elapsed: 102.94 s
INFO:  scanned index "sensormodeidx" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 9.13 s, system: 0.99 s, elapsed: 43.63 s
INFO:  scanned index "timerangeidx" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 11.79 s, system: 1.62 s, elapsed: 60.37 s
INFO:  scanned index "unq_satelliteproduct_0" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 13.38 s, system: 3.42 s, elapsed: 106.99 s
INFO:  scanned index "footgeogidx" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 30.42 s, system: 15.87 s, elapsed: 296.25 s
INFO:  scanned index "starttimeidx" to remove 7555703 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 15.63 s, system: 1.45 s, elapsed: 37.39 s

INFO:  "satelliteproduct": removed 7555703 row versions in 2869127 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 44.09 s, system: 71.27 s, elapsed: 988.56 s
INFO:  index "satelliteproduct_pkey" now contains 43594250 row versions in 455245 pages
DETAIL:  636552 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "supplierproductidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 666798 pages
DETAIL:  636608 index row versions were removed.
68878 index pages have been deleted, 68878 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "sensormodeidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 282910 pages
DETAIL:  636608 index row versions were removed.
50164 index pages have been deleted, 49125 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "timerangeidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 389866 pages
DETAIL:  636608 index row versions were removed.
49768 index pages have been deleted, 47283 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "unq_satelliteproduct_0" now contains 43594250 row versions in 693222 pages
DETAIL:  559271 index row versions were removed.
78266 index pages have been deleted, 78266 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  index "footgeogidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 651770 pages
DETAIL:  6631953 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 1.83 s, system: 2.73 s, elapsed: 100.58 s.
INFO:  index "starttimeidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 159747 pages
DETAIL:  7467607 index row versions were removed.
20350 index pages have been deleted, 3620 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "satelliteproduct": found 363675 removable, 26890882 nonremovable row versions in 5931351 out of 9092079 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 224173
There were 7774835 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 136118 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 196.80 s, system: 134.80 s, elapsed: 2722.42 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_17987"
INFO:  scanned index "pg_toast_17987_index" to remove 455 row versions
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.59 s, system: 0.06 s, elapsed: 3.21 s
INFO:  "pg_toast_17987": removed 455 row versions in 131 pages
DETAIL:  CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
INFO:  index "pg_toast_17987_index" now contains 7505213 row versions in 20884 pages
DETAIL:  455 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  "pg_toast_17987": found 276 removable, 61422 nonremovable row versions in 6540 out of 366398 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 224173
There were 168 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.65 s, system: 0.10 s, elapsed: 4.39 s.
VACUUM
```

I checked for anything stopping the vacuum process from working properly

No long queries, no lingering replication slots, no stale prepared statements...

```
 slot_name | slot_type | database | xmin
-----------+-----------+----------+------
(0 rows)

 gid | prepared | owner | database | xmin
-----+----------+-------+----------+------
(0 rows)
```

I rerun the vacuum verbose this time to check all was fine

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE) satelliteproduct;
INFO:  vacuuming "public.satelliteproduct"
INFO:  index "footgeogidx" now contains 43594250 row versions in 651770 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 1.86 s, system: 2.73 s, elapsed: 99.72 s.
INFO:  "satelliteproduct": found 0 removable, 7 nonremovable row versions in 1 out of 9092079 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 224173
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 340829 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 2.23 s, system: 2.73 s, elapsed: 100.15 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_17987"
INFO:  "pg_toast_17987": found 0 removable, 23 nonremovable row versions in 1 out of 366398 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 224173
There were 0 unused item pointers.
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
0 pages are entirely empty.
CPU: user: 0.01 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.01 s.
VACUUM
```

BUT I still get the same query times, ie < 1ms for supplierproduct_id = '123' and > 1mn for supplierproduct_id IN('123', '123')

EDIT 3

I am also adding the full explain analyze for the tqo queries I mentioned in my initial message

```
explain analyze select *
from satelliteproduct
where supplier_id = 226
and supplierproduct_id IN ('123', '234');
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using unq_satelliteproduct_0 on satelliteproduct  (cost=0.69..2.71 rows=1 width=2593) (actual time=11781.933..11781.935 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (supplier_id = 226)
   Filter: ((supplierproduct_id)::text = ANY ('{123,234}'::text[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2767533
 Planning Time: 0.247 ms
 Execution Time: 11808.777 ms
(6 rows)


explain analyze select *
from satelliteproduct
where supplier_id = 5129
and supplierproduct_id IN ('123', '234');
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using unq_satelliteproduct_0 on satelliteproduct  (cost=0.69..4.41 rows=1 width=2593) (actual time=4.546..4.547 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((supplier_id = 5129) AND ((supplierproduct_id)::text = ANY ('{123,234}'::text[])))
 Planning Time: 0.215 ms
 Execution Time: 4.590 ms
(4 rows)
```

Small update. I reindexed all my indexes as they were quite bloated. Didn't change anything unfortunately with the queries.

Comment: this question is not geo related, maybe you move it to another forum

Comment: Have you attempted dropping and rebuilding the indices? Perhaps the index did finish building correctly before you shutdown, and its cross reference index is incomplete with 226?

Comment: For performance questions, please provide information as instructed here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info Should get clear as soon as we have that.

Comment: Neither of those two plans shows a Seq Scan. When you post a plan, make sure you preserve the indention as that is vital to understanding the plan. You should also show the **complete** plan, not only the parts that you think are important.  To complete the picture, please also [edit] your question and add the `create table` and `create index` statements.

Comment: In addition to ahwnn request, what is the expected and actual number of rows with supplier_id = 226, leaving aside the other restriction?

Comment: I edited and updated as per comments. @jjanes, there are a few million rows for that value. The weird thing is if I drop the supplier_id condition then the query is super fast. It's as if the supplier_id select botches everything with the planner.

Comment: (ctd...) makes me think the issue is with the unq_satelliteproduct_0. I am reindexing all my indexes as they were very bloated. I'll see if that improves anything.

Comment: I don't understand how returning a few million rows could be super fast.  That is always going to take some time.

Comment: I'm not returning a few million rows? my select only returns the rows with ids matching the ones in the IN statement, at most 2 in my example above.

Comment: " if I drop the supplier_id condition then the query is super fast"  How is a condition that no longer exists causing rows not to be returned?

Comment: in those tables there is a unicity on (supplier id and supplier product id), but not necessarily a unicity on supplier product id. That said the chances of having two rows with the same supplier product id but with a different supplier id are quite slim and they can be filtered in my Java application.